# Writing an array of floating points to a file

Tags: java, file

I am trying to store an arraylist of floating points to a file.
I tried using a DataOutputStream to write to the file and it works just fine except that the data is not written in human-readable format.
I know I must use print writer to write the data in text format, however it does not support writing floating points.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
writer.write(naiveNearestPoints(points.get(i))); //Gives an error
writer.println(naiveNearestPoints(points.get(i)));//**updated** correct way to do it
```

Is there any other way I could write floating points to a file in a readable format?

Comment: The question is only not appropriate because you have no code. Please [edit]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java 

Literally LMGTFY

Comment: Try PrintWriter which is designed for text. DataOutputStream is designed for binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrintWriter` does support writing floating point values: [`print(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print-float-) and [`print(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print-double-).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by this?

> it does not support writing floating points

The `PrintWriter` can, in fact, `print(float)` or `print(double)`

---

If that isn't working for you, then if you can `System.out.print` a floating point, you can almost as easily write to a file by redirecting `System.out` into a `File`.

For example

```
File out = new File("out.txt");
try {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

// loops over list, print with System.out.print
```

Comment: I was trying to do something like this                                                     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("NaiveSolution.txt");  writer.write(naiveNearestPoints(points.get(i)));                                                   And since that was giving me an error so I thought I couldn't write floating points using PrintWriter. But now I get it and thanks!

Comment: You didn't show code in the question. My answer is just an example of writing to a file, which there are several ways to do in Java

Comment: My bad, I should've done that. Sorry and thanks again!

Comment: This ruins the ability to print to the terminal for no benefit. It's a very bad idea to use `System.setOut` here rather than just making a new `PrintWriter` or `PrintStream` and using that directly.

Comment: @Chai So? It's just a simple example. Not like I run this in production

Comment: People coming here actually use the code examples in answers. Yours has a huge drawback for literally no reason and no warning about that. The code in the edited question is two lines and doesn't have that drawback.

Comment: @Chai I'm not here to argue, so I accept your downvote. Please carry on.

Comment: @Chai People coming here certainly shouldn't use any code from an answer without understanding what it does.

Comment: Besides, the question only asked "Is there any other way I could write floating points to a file in a readable format?"... And I showed there is another way.